# Setting BLE Advertising Address using Tiny-Go Bluetooth

Tags: go, raspberry-pi, bluetooth, bluetooth-lowenergy, tinygo

I'm using Tiny-Go's [bluetooth](https://github.com/tinygo-org/bluetooth) to generate Bluetooth Low Energy (BLE) messages on a Raspberry Pi 4 (Raspbian, Linux 6.1.21, Bluez 5.55) like this:

```
    adv := constants.Adapter.DefaultAdvertisement()
    if err = adv.Configure(bluetooth.AdvertisementOptions{
        LocalName:        "Go BLE",
    }); err != nil {
        log.Fatalf("Error configuring advertisement: %v\n", err)
    }


    if err = adv.Start(); err != nil {
        log.Fatalf("Error starting advertisements: %v\n", err)
    }
```

This works fine. But, I'm trying to change the Bluetooth address my device is using to send the advertisements. I've tried using the [`Set()`](https://pkg.go.dev/tinygo.org/x/bluetooth#MACAddress.Set) function to change the MAC address of the adapter, which does not throw an error but also does not appear to affect the BLE MAC address used in the advertisements.

Is there a way to change the advertising MAC address using Tiny-Go's `bluetooth` library? If not, is there a way I can change it using `bluetoothctl` or `btmgmt`?

Comment: Just curious: why do you want to change the address?

Comment: Fair question! Due to the limited size of BLE advertisements (27 bytes with manufacturer-specific advertisement data), I'm attempting to use the address to squeeze out a few more bytes that I control.

Comment: In case you do not find a solution: I think you could also use the ServiceUUIDs in your AdvertisementOptions to do this. We had a project where we used the advertised service uuids to differentiate between device types by setting custom uuids in our advertisement data